# C++ printing 10 elements per line

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

I have a question to ask. How can I get it to print 10 elements per line of an ARRAY.

For example:

```
88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11  
11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88
88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11  
11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88
88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11  
11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88
88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11  
11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88
88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11  
11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88 11 88
```

here's my current code:

```
int main()
{
    int test[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++){
            if ((i+j)%2 == 0){
                test[i][j] = 88;
            }
            else if ((i+j)%2 == 1){
                test[i][j] = 11;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What's the code should I add to get it to print 10 elements per line? Please help me D: Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What is the value of ARRAY_SIZE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int test[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++){
            if ((i+j)%2 == 0){
                test[i][j] = 88;
            }
            else if ((i+j)%2 == 1){
                test[i][j] = 11;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++){
            std::cout << test[i][j] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. this looks like assigment/homework

   - so i will not provide source code ...
   - is this for console output?
   - if not specify target ...
2. your code just fills the array

   - to print you need to add 2 nested for loops (i,j) through entire array
   - similar to what you already have
   - and inside output array element test[i][j] instead of setting its value
   - to output on screen use what you are used to (or what you have used at class...)
   - for example `cout` from iostream.h or `printf` from stdio.h or conio.h not sure now did not use these archaisms for more then a decade
3. `10` values per line

   - every time you output ASCII code 13 (Enter) it means new line
   - for console target device it also do a line feed to do left side
   - so to achieve what you want just add `cout << endl;` or `printf("\n");`
   - after every 10th value is outed ...
   - so before the nested for's add some counter `int k=0;`
   - inside loops increment it and add `if (k>=10) { k=0; cout <<endl;  }`
   - depending on the order of how you put all this together you may be
   - will need to change the `10` by +/-1 to match 10 values per line
   - do not forget to add some space between values otherwise their will merge to single number ...
4. raster target devices

   - for non console devices like bitmaps ...
   - you need to compute the output x,y position of each value your self
   - so before loops add `int x=x0,y=y0; // start position for output`
   - each time you increment `k`, add also `x+=width_for_single_value;`
   - and each time you set `k` back to zero add `y+=height_for_single_value; x=x0;`
5. column align

   - for that you can use formating like `printf("%4i ",test[i][j]);`
   - or add the spaces/zeros your self according to outputted value size
   - for example something like this:
   - `int val=123;`
   - `if (val<10) cout << "0";`
   - `if (val<100) cout << "0";`
   - `if (val<1000) cout << "0";`
   - `if (val<10000) cout << "0";`
   - `cout << val << " ";`
   - if you are outputting to text file you can use Tabulator ASCII code 9 or '\t'